# How to catch the URL with data if using an API in php

Tags: php, mysql, api

I've been trying to figure out how to catch the whole URL of a website which uses an API.  I have one script which pass data using API and also I have an API which processes the posted data. The inserting works but it inserts empty data in my database.

Here's my API

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'datauser');
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');

$method = strtolower(array_shift($url_send));

if ($method = 'post') {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$cell = $_GET['cell'];
}



switch ($method) {
case 'get':
  //$sql = "select * from users WHERE user_lname= '$name'"; break;
case 'put':
  //$sql = "update users set $set where user_lname=$name"; break;
case 'post':
  $sql = "insert into users (user_fname, user_lname, user_contact) values ('$name', '$name', '$cell')"; break;
case 'delete':
  //$sql = "delete users where id=$key"; break;
}

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if ($method == 'post') {
echo mysqli_insert_id($link);
}

die();
```

Now here's my code which uses the said API above

```
<?php
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));

$data = array(
"table" => $request[0],
"FNAME" => $request[1],
"LNAME" => $request[2],
"CNTCT" => $request[3]
);

$url_send ="http://localhost/api.php?   id=".$request[0]."&name=".$request[1]."&cell=".$request[3];
$str_data = json_encode($data);
$post_elements = array('data'=>$data);


function sendPostData($url){
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($url_send));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($response);
 return $response;
}

 echo sendPostData($url_send);

?>
```

The error I'm receiving is this one

```
**
Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: cell in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 11
21**
```

The **21** is the ID I recently inserted. The insert works but It seems I cannot actually grab the data from the URL.

Someone, please help. Greatly appreciated any advise, comment even negative ones.

Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You haven't set `$url_send` in the API script, so what is `$method = strtolower($url_send);` supposed to do?

Comment: If you want to send the whole URL from the caller to the API, you need to pass it as a URL parameter or in the post fields.

Comment: But why should an API need to know anything about the URL of the caller? An API should be usable from any caller, it shouldn't depend on the caller's URL.